# labels (package): How to fit address text to the size of label in labels package?

Tags: fontsize, sticky-labels

The following code produces **address labels**.

What I am trying to achieve is to **fit text to the size of the box** created by [labels](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/labels) package, this solves the problem with the address is big and overflows the box.

Any pointers to this:

```
\documentclass[12,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf}
\usepackage{labels}
\LabelCols=3
\LabelRows=7
\LeftBorder=8mm
\RightBorder=4mm
\TopBorder=14mm
\BottomBorder=11mm
\LabelGridtrue
\LabelInfotrue
\begin{document}
\begin{labels}
\input{Address.dat}
\end{labels}
\end{document}
```

Contents of `Address.dat`

```
E3
XX XXsfdsf 
23,fds sdkfjhdsfkj
fkdfjdskfjh s kjdsf
sdfds sfsdf 4564856

E4 %Bigger adress
sdfsdf dfsdfsd, sdfdsf, sdfsdfs sdfsdfsd dfsd
sdfsfdsfsd sdflkjsdf, sdfsdjldasdsdskdflsd  fasdfdsf
asdsd dfgrettwe 5223502 sdfsdfsdf asdGGHkdsjfhkkjSJGHjg 
sdfdsfsd fdsfsdsdfweweqw weeqweqw


E5
rtretertert rtwer
plpokpqlkdlkpo 
lklkllsdkfjwlek 6787686986

E6
rtretertert rtwer
plpokpqlkdlkpo 
lklkllsdkfjwlek 6787686986
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **manual approach**. I also deleted irrelevant (regarding the problem) code.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Provides \scalebox
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Provided by the OP
\usepackage{labels}
\LabelCols=3
\LabelRows=7
\LeftBorder=8mm
\RightBorder=4mm
\TopBorder=14mm
\BottomBorder=11mm
\LabelGridtrue
\LabelInfotrue

\newcommand{\mySampleText}{Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text }

\begin{document}
% ----- Start of Labels -----
\begin{labels}

% Label 1
    \textbf{Label 1}
    \mySampleText
    \mySampleText
    \mySampleText


% Label 2
    \textbf{Label 2}
    \mySampleText
    \mySampleText
    \mySampleText
    \mySampleText
    \mySampleText

% Label 3 (same as Label 2)
    \scalebox{0.7}{ % --> Scaled to 70 %
    % minipage is needed since scalebox acts like \mbox (--> no line breaks)
    % Found here (German): https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-W%C3%B6rterbuch:_scalebox
    \begin{minipage}{\the\textwidth}
        \textbf{Label 3}
        \mySampleText
        \mySampleText
        \mySampleText
        \mySampleText
        \mySampleText
    \end{minipage}
    }

\end{labels}
% ----- End of Labels -----
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have upvoted this answer, but an automatic solution would be better.